# Connection to mongodb module - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I'm a newbie working with Node JS and MongoDB, looking through the internet I've come to make this module to get a connection to mongo. My questions are

- Is it okay ?
- How can I improve it
- Is there a way to do this with generators ES6 ?

Here is my code:

```
"use strict"
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    db: 't1'
};

var mdb = null,
    uri = `mongodb://${config.host}:${config.port}/${config.db}`;

module.exports = {

    connect: () => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, db) => {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    mdb = db;
                    return resolve();
                }
            });

        });
    },

    get: () => {
        return mdb;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a widely use [ODM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Data_Manager) for database connectivity. You can choose [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) which is very useful and provide many features like middle ware, schema design, type casting, validators. This module is used by websites like Linkedin, Datafox etc. 
As Mongo is a non structured DB, It will help you to design your database and adding constraint also.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use your `mdb` var in your `resolve` callback of your **Promise**, but I think the best way is use the Mongoose ODM for MongoDB.